# block a website using iptables (redirecting to an error page)

Tags: linux, apache, networking, iptables

would be technically possible block a website with a specific iptables rule and in the same time returning to the user browser an error page?

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.1.19 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.20:80
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you totally block port 80 traffic from an IP address with iptables, your web server will never get any request from that client and thus be unable to serve an error page. So in short, no.

To achieve what you are asking, one solution would be to port forward to another port or host that serves only error pages.  The iptables rules for doing that will be specific to your situation.  But in doing so, the packets will still be traversing your network.

You may be better off asking this question over at [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/)...